# How to configure PostgreSQL to accept all incoming connections

Tags: postgresql

I've got a PostgreSQL data base that I'd like to configure to accept all incoming connections regardless of the source IP address. How can this be configured in the `pg_hba.conf` file? I'm using postgreSQL version 8.4.

Answer (score 339, accepted):

Just use `0.0.0.0/0`.

```
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0            md5
```

Make sure the [`listen_addresses`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-connection.html#GUC-LISTEN-ADDRESSES) in `postgresql.conf` (or [`ALTER SYSTEM SET`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altersystem.html)) allows incoming connections on all available IP interfaces.

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

After the changes you have to reload the configuration. One way to do this is execute this `SELECT` as a superuser.

```sql
SELECT pg_reload_conf();
```

Note: to change `listen_addresses`, a reload is not enough, and you have to restart the server.

Comment: does this really work with type `md5`?  I thought it would be necessary to use type `trust`...

Comment: "trust" allows all users to connect without any password. That's something I wouldn't use, a password is the bare minimum you should always use. Even on your own computer.

Comment: ah, i read the question differently -- i thought he meant accept connections from all clients unconditionally (for some unimportant testbed, maybe).  i see what you're getting at now.

Comment: **NOTE**: If your network is IPv6, you need to use `::/0` as opposed to `0.0.0.0/0` when modifying the pg_hba.conf file.

Comment: To change the listen port I had restart PostgreSQL: `service postgresql restart`

Comment: Make sure `postgres` has strong password: `sudo -u postgres psql`, `\password`.

Comment: I will mention that if you are running your database locally only, as in the db can only be accessed from the local machine, running with no password is both hassle free and as secure as running with the most encrypted password you can come up with. If someone has gained access to the machine then they can just as easily make modifications to whatever they want to then grant themselves access to the db as well.

Answer (score 76):

`0.0.0.0/0` for all IPv4 addresses

`::0/0` for all IPv6 addresses

`all` to match any IP address

`samehost` to match any of the server's own IP addresses

`samenet` to match any address in any subnet that the server is directly connected to.

e.g.

```
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0            md5
```

Comment: And md5 ???  I have an idea, but may wanna include it

Comment: It's great that you included an ipv6 example too, thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Addition to above great answers, if you want some range of IPs to be authorized, you could edit `/var/lib/pgsql/{VERSION}/data` file and put something like

`host    all             all             172.0.0.0/8        trust`

It will accept incoming connections from any host of the above range.
Source: http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/database_guides/Practical_PostgreSQL_database/c15679_002.htm

Answer (score 9):

Configuration all files with postgres 12 on centos:

**step 1:** search and edit file

> sudo vi /var/lib/pgsql/12/data/pg_hba.conf

press "i" and at line IPv4 change

```
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0            md5
```

**step 2:** search and edit file postgresql.conf

> sudo vi /var/lib/pgsql/12/data/postgresql.conf

add last line: listen_addresses = '*'
:wq! (save file)

**step 3:**  restart

> systemctl restart postgresql-12.service

Answer (score 4):

Go to pg_hba.conf file in this location (/etc/postgresql/12/main) and add the following line at the end:

```
host  all  all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
```

It allows access to all databases for all users.

Restart Postgresql by writing this command

```
service postgresql restart
```

For further info, check out [error details](https://www.techaeblogs.live/2022/11/could-not-connect-to-postgresql-fatal-no-pg-hba-conf-entry-for-host.html)

Answer (score -12):

Add this line to **pg_hba.conf** of postgres folder

```
host    all    all    all    trust
```

"trust" allows all users to connect without any password.

Comment: Can you maybe add some commentary to the code? Where to put it and how it works?

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: allow connections from all ips is really insecure