# Peer authentication failed for user "geo" geodjango tutorial postgresql error

Tags: postgresql, authentication, postgis, geodjango

I'm starting the [geodjango](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/) tutorial. I've copy and past everythings but I still get the error.

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "geo"
```

I'm new to geodjango and postgresql and postgis. I've made a fresh install of postgresql and postgis.

I create the geo user as in the doc.

> $ sudo su - postgres
>   $ createuser --createdb geo
>   $ exit

I can't figure how to resolve it.

Here is my settings:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
     'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
     'NAME': 'geodjango',
     'USER': 'geo',
     # 'HOST': 'localhost', I tried this but didn't work
     # 'PASSWORD': '***', I tried it too using a password but didn't work
 }
```

}

Answer (score 2):

So I find a solution, the geodjango tutorial is not working.

> sudo -i -u postgres

then:

> psql

then:

> CREATE USER username;
>
> ALTER ROLE username WITH CREATEDB;
>
> ALTER USER username WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'password';

and I have my settings like this:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
     'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
     'NAME': 'geodjango',
     'USER': 'username',
     'HOST': 'localhost',
     'PASSWORD': '****',
 }
```

}

Comment: After this I get: 5432 failed: FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "geo".

Comment: The problem may also be reproduced for Peer authentication. The solution however seems to be:
`sudo nano /var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf`,
where one should change peer or ident to md5, and then update `settings.py` DATABASES with appropriate USER and PASSWORD.

Answer (score 0):

Peer authentication Errors are usually caused by a bad pg_hba.conf file. There are entries in your file, that prevent your user from executing queries.

The pg_hba.conf is located in your postgres-data directory and defines basic configurations of your postgres-installation. In your case, the database gets a request, but denies the processing, because your user is not autheticated to perform the request.

Log in as your postgres-user:

```
sudo su - postgres
```

edit the file, with the editor of your choice (I use emacs):

```
emacs -nw data/pg_hba.conf
```

change the access-restrictions: Here it becomes tricky. If your have a postgres-Installation to play and develop with (not in production) you may set access to 'trust':

change:

```
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0            ident
```

to:

```
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0            trust
```

However, if you use the Database in production, **don't set it to trust!**. Instead configure it to check against passwords / hashes.

```
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0            md5
```

Here are some Links, that might help out:

[Link to the docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html)

[Question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278379/how-to-configure-postgresql-to-accept-all-incoming-connections)