# How to connect spring boot web app to postgresql database

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, ubuntu, firewall

I'm working on a Spring boot project and i tried to connect my server to a postgresql database.
When i run the program with my IDE (on my windows OS) it's working but when i make a jar file and run it on my ubuntu server virtual machine which host my DB it doesn't work.

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
```

I've check my firewall rules but still no sucess.

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

I make some research and I heard about the configuration files of postgresql to modify but it still doesn't work and i have no idea where the issue comes.

Below the lines that i've modified on postgresql.conf:

```
listen_addresses = '*'          # what IP address(es) to listen on;
ssl = on
```

and for the pg_hba.conf:

```
local   all             postgres                                peer
local   all             kapitax                                trust
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
#host   all             kapitax        *                       password
#host   all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all             *                       trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             *                       password
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 password
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             *                       md5
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 md5
```

The issue can comes from the applcation.properties code ?

```
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/kapitax
spring.datasource.username=kapitax
spring.datasource.password=kapitax
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
server.port=8090
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
#host   all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
```

should be enabled like:

```
host   all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
```

With `0.0.0.0/0` you will listen for all IPv4 addresses. After you change this configuration make sure to reload your server settings or restart the database server. A more detailed explanation can be found in the following answer: [How to configure PostgreSQL to accept all incoming connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278379/how-to-configure-postgresql-to-accept-all-incoming-connections)

Comment: Thank you, indeed the issue comes from the the commented line. I removed the # and It Works !