# Importing shapefiles in postgresql in linux using pgadmin 4

Tags: linux, postgresql, postgis, pgadmin-4

I am new to postGIS, I was following [this](https://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/loading_data.html)
tutorial.

> I can't get past the installation part because the instructions are outdated.

I got stuck when it says `return to the Dashboard, and click on the Import shapefiles link in the PostGIS section.`

I am using pgadmin 4 and I am unable to find the postGIS section there.

Comment: Having the same issue. Its frustrating that this is the "go to" tutorial but that you cant get past the installation part because the instructions are outdated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're simply trying to import shapefiles into PostgreSQL, you might wanna take a look at [`shp2pgsql`](https://www.geoportal.rlp.de/mediawiki/index.php/Shp2pgsql).

Data sample: [`TM_WORLD_BORDERS_SIMPL-0.3.zip`](http://thematicmapping.org/downloads/TM_WORLD_BORDERS_SIMPL-0.3.zip)

After unpacking your zip file just execute the following line in your console:

```
$ shp2pgsql -I -s 4326 TM_WORLD_BORDERS_SIMPL-0.3.shp table_world | psql -d mydb
```

Things to take into account:

- `table_world` is the name of the target table
- `psql -d mydb` takes into account that your current operating system user has an account in the database, that no password is required, that the database is installed at localhost and that it listens at the the standard port `5432`. Check the [`psql`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/app-psql.html) documentation to build your own connection command, e.g. `psql -U myuser -h 192.168.1.42 -p 5434 -d mydb` to login with the user `myuser` in the database `mydb` in the remote PostgreSQL at `192.168.1.42` that listens at the port `5434`. In case your PostgreSQL isn't configured to accept connections, check this [`answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3278835/2275388).
- `4326` is the identifier for WGS84, which is the spatial reference system of this shapefile - and the most often used worldwide.

.. and your data is ready to be played with. Screenshot from the [`geometry viewer`](http://www.bostongis.com/blog/index.php?/archives/272-pgAdmin4-now-offers-PostGIS-geometry-viewer.html) of pgAdmin4:

[image]

Further reading:

- [`psql`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/app-psql.html)
- [`shp2pgsql tutorial`](https://www.igismap.com/import-shapefile-postgresql/)