# Importing shapefile is failed

Tags: postgresql, postgis, shapefile, esri

I am beginner of PostGIS. I am trying to import shapefile to PostGIS. But the file is not imported. What can I solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Would you care to show us how you tried to import the data?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing shapefiles in postgresql in linux using pgadmin 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60036327/importing-shapefiles-in-postgresql-in-linux-using-pgadmin-4)

Comment: I guess it is not

Comment: I uploaded the ss.

Comment: can you open this shapefile in qgis, save as another shapefile and import it again? It seems that the dbf (toc file!) is either corrupt or just not readable.

Comment: I did it but it does not work

Comment: odd. in this case I would try using `shp2pgql`. the error message is actually clear: the dbf file cannot be opened. now you need to investigate why :) normally I would ask you to share your shapefile, so that I can try it out myself, but since I do not have windows I am afraid it won't shed any light on your problem

Comment: I am very grateful to you. I send to e-mail  you..Thank you for everything.

Comment: I am sorry I sent to wrong file because of similarity of file name. I send to right file now.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to import a CSV with a Shapefile importer. To import your CSV file first create a table that corresponds to the CSV file structure, e.g. based on your CSV:

```
CREATE TABLE t (
  a INT,
  b TEXT,
  c TEXT,
  d TEXT,
  e TEXT,
  f TEXT,
  g TEXT,
  lat NUMERIC,
  long NUMERIC,
  j INT
);
```

Then import it using a tool like `psql`:

```
$ cat fastfoodmaps_locations_2007.csv | psql -d yourdb -c "COPY t FROM STDIN CSV;"
```

Or simply connect to your database using `psql` and from there run

```
\copy t FROM C:\path_to_csv_file\fastfoodmaps_locations_2007.csv CSV
```

.. then you will see your data:

```
SELECT * FROM t LIMIT 5;
 a | b |             c             |     d     | e  |   f   |       g        |   lat   |   long   | j 
---+---+---------------------------+-----------+----+-------+----------------+---------+----------+---
 1 | b | 3601 N.W. 27th Avenue     | Miami     | FL | 33142 | (305) 638-3838 | 25.8092 |   -80.24 | 0
 2 | b | 8995 N. W. 7th Avenue     | Miami     | FL | 33150 | (305) 754-8453 | 25.8587 | -80.2094 | 0
 3 | b | 30390 South Dixie Highway | Homestead | FL | 33030 | (305) 247-7181 | 25.4849 |  -80.461 | 0
 4 | b | 7975 N. W. 27th Avenue    | Miami     | FL | 33147 | (305) 836-8152 | 25.8471 | -80.2415 | 0
 5 | b | 9201 South Dixie Highway  | Miami     | FL | 33156 | (305) 666-1130 | 25.6849 | -80.3125 | 0
```