# Can not connect to Postgres on Docker from Application on Docker

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, docker

I am trying to connect to Docker Postgres DB from Spring Boot Application running also on Docker
[image]

Error I have:
Unable to determine Dialect without JDBC metadata

There is no problem to connect to this database if I will just run application from IntelliJ itself. Using Spring Boot 3 with Postgres:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>42.7.1</version>
</dependency>
```

and Jackarta jakarta.persistence-api version 3.1.0

Postgres Docker image 16.2 - exposing port 5432:5432 - And I can connect to it when running app from IntelliJ

Comment: localhost points to the docker container you are running on. I doubt you are running the postgres on the same docker container. Either use a docker compose file to start up both and use the servicen ame of the postgres container, or create a shared network between both. Either way you need to reference the service name and not localhost.

Comment: Please review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74967111/failure-to-connect-to-postgres-docker-container-running-locally

Comment: you'd need to add the docker deployment config for your postgres instance to get a good answer to this. If postgres is running on a docker container within a docker container, you'll need to obtain the ip-address/hostname of the postgres instance from within the docker container.